# get list_box from sql RUBY/shoes GUI

Tags: sql, ruby, shoes

i have one problem
How do I insert a list from the database in a listbox

Example i trying

```
$row_user = $db.execute( "SELECT user FROM usuarios" )
$row_user.each do |row|
@users = list_box :items => [row[0]]
end
```

but I know he has repeated many list box

tried

```
@users = list_box :items => $row_user
```

but returns values ​​with `["user"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with green_shoes but it should work with any color, just add the flatten to your array $row_user

```
@users = list_box :items => $row_user.flatten
```

here a working sample

```
require 'green_shoes'

app = Shoes.app :width => 500, :height => 600 do
  users = [["peter"], ["joe"]]
  stack do
    users = list_box :items => users.flatten
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

got it with

```
edit_line $row_user.join
```

for one value